# How do I make figure full screen in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fullscreen, matlab-figure

please, this question is not that simple, you may think it is already answered but it is not the case.

I know how to make a **next figure** in full screen :

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
```

But what I want is not the **next figure** . But figure Number 3 `figure(3)`

and again the *Figure Property Number* is not working.

Please, How to make the figure 3 full screen ?

PS: I am using Matlab 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `set()` will do what you want (sources [here](https://machinelearning1.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/create-and-maximize-a-figure-in-matlab/) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)).

```
figure(1), figure(2), figure(3), figure(4)
set(figure(3), 'Position', get(0, 'Screensize'));
```

Comment: `h3 = figure(3) `
`set(h3, 'Position', get(0, 'Screensize'));`